# Shell script to read latest version from artifactory

Tags: bash, shell, sh, artifactory

In my artifactory there is a file **"maven-metadata.xml"**, which contains all version. I wanted to pick up latest version from this file. But the issue is I want to pickup a stable version.
For example in this maven-metadata.xml file:

```html
<metadata>
<groupId>com.platform</groupId>
<artifactId>abc1.2</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>2.6.0-425-75b5083</latest>
    <release>2.6.0-425-75b5083</release>
    <versions>
      <version>2.5.0-132-b616a37</version>
      <version>2.5.1-RC1</version>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <version>2.6.0-425-75b5083</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20201011113748</lastUpdated>
 </versioning>
</metadata>
```

But I would like to pickup the latest stable version (without alphanumeric) i.e. 2.5.2
How to filter this data in shell script?

Also I cannot directly read `<latest>` tag as it may contain alphanumeric version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming versions are sorted ascendingly, you can use the following command to extract latest version without alphanumeric.

```
sed -n 's/.*<version>\([0-9.]*\)<\/version>.*/\1/p' maven-metadata.xml | tail -n 1
```